# Positioning an element via javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to position an element by percentage but it didn't work out for me, it worked only when I used pixels.

Here is my code:

```
var x=document.getElementById("fir")
x.style.position = "absolute";
x.style.left = 10%
x.style.top = 10%
```

If I assigned to `x.style.left` any number followed by nothing it works fine but if I put percentage after the number like it's shown in the code above it doesn't work. Any ideas on how can I use the percentage to position this element?

Answer (score 9):

Those values are supposed to be strings:

```
x.style.left = '10%';
x.style.top = '10%';
```

Otherwise, the `%` sign is interpreted as the [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators), leading to unexpected results or syntax errors (depending on your use of semicolons).

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to assign it as a string. You're syntax is invalid, because `10%` means something in JavaScript, so it's actually parsing `x.style.left = 10%x.style.top = 10%` since JS ignores whitespace.

Like bfavaretto said, you need to assign the values as strings:

```
x.style.left = '10%';
x.style.top = '10%';
```

and make sure you add your semicolons. :)

Comment: You're right, I missed that the first part is not a syntax error due to the missing semicolon. The last one still is, though.

Answer (score 1):

The `%` is CSS syntax, not javascript syntax and you need to wrap it in quotes:

```
var x=document.getElementById("fir")
x.style.position = "absolute";
x.style.left = "10%";
x.style.top = "10%";
```